# Discrete random variables statistics question: why is my method incorrect?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

This was a question in my A-level further statistics textbook. I understand how to get the correct answer, but I'm not sure why my method is wrong. The question is as follows:

> John runs a pizza parlour that sells pizza in three sizes: small (20cm diameter), medium (30cm diameter) and large (40 cm diameter). Each pizza base is 1cm thick. John has worked out that on average, customers order a small, medium or large pizza with probabilities $\frac{3}{10}$, $\frac{9}{20}$ and $\frac{5}{20}$ respectively. Calculate the expected amount of pizza dough needed per customer.

The correct answer to the question was $726.5$ $cm^3$, found by calculating the probability for each possible pizza volume, and then finding the expected value for the volume.

However, my method involved calculating the expected value for the diameter of the pizza, and using that to find the radius, and from there, the volume (my working out below).

These methods do not give the same result, with the latter giving a volume of only $683.5$ $cm^3$. To me, these seem like different methods of finding the same answer, but I am not sure why the answers are different. Can anyone explain to me why my method does not work?

| $x$ | $20$ | $30$ | $40$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $P(X=x)$ | $\frac{3}{10}$ | $\frac{9}{20}$ | $\frac{5}{20}$ |

$E(X) = \frac{20\times3}{10} + \frac{30\times9}{20} + \frac{40\times5}{20}$
$E(X) = 6 + \frac{27}{2} + 10 = 29.5$ $cm$ diameter.
Radius $= 14.75$ $cm$.
$\pi \times 14.75^2 \times 1 = 683.5$ $cm^3$ of dough.

Comment: in general $E(X^2)\neq E(X)^{2}$. The expected volume is $E((\frac{X}{2})^{2}\cdot \pi \cdot 1)$ but what you did was $\left(\frac{E(X)}{2}\right)^{2}\cdot \pi \cdot 1$.

Comment: @FZan thanks for the explanation, I hadn't thought about it that way.